# How can I remove a specific element from an Array in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm a beginner to vanilla JS and was building this program to remove a specific item from an array. However it's bit tricky.

```
let cart = ['bread', 'milk', 'rice'];


while (6 > 0){
    let remove = prompt("Enter The Item You Want to Remove");
    if (remove.toLowerCase() === "done"){
        break
    }
    else{
        for (let j = 0; j < cart.length; j++){
            if (remove.toLowerCase() === cart[j].toLowerCase()){
                cart.splice(cart[j],1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you give me the solution to remove a specific item from an array.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let cart = ['milk', 'bread', 'rice'];

let removed = prompt("Type the item you want to remove");
let index = cart.indexOf(removed.toLowerCase())
if (index > -1) {
  cart.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(cart);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let cart = ['bread', 'milk', 'rice'];
    
    const index = cart.indexOf('bread');
    if (index > -1) {
      cart.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(cart);
```

Comment: 1- Ignoring the case is required. for example, MILK doesn't work.
2- We need to get the value from the user, not bypassing it.
check my answer

Comment: @HakunaMatata I didn't write complete code where a user can copy and paste, as per question I tried to give the logic how we can implement it now validation and on demand value we can get as per our need.

Comment: Chill dude! no offense :) first, I didn't copy-paste any code, and I'm just explaining the request in this question.

Comment: @HakunaMatata sorry friend, you took my word other way :)  My intention was, everyone should put some effort so that they can understand how the things are working not just copy and paste to make it work.

Comment: I'm sorry, English is my 4th language so I struggle sometimes. I didn't understand well. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

Just refactored the "for loop" block code and added the validation for the input value.

```js
let cart = ['bread', 'milk', 'rice'];

while (6 > 0) {
    let remove = prompt("Enter The Item You Want to Remove");
    if (remove.toLowerCase() === "done" && remove.toLowerCase() !== "") {
        console.log(cart)
        break
    }
    else {
        let index = cart.indexOf(remove);
        if (index > -1) {
            cart.splice(index, 1);
            console.log(cart);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Just refactored the "for loop" block code and added the validation for the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass index for the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```js
let cart = ['bread', 'milk', 'rice'];


while (6 > 0){
    let remove = prompt("Enter The Item You Want to Remove");
    if (remove.toLowerCase() === "done"){
        console.log(cart)
        break
    }
    else{
        for (let j = 0; j < cart.length; j++){
            if (remove.toLowerCase() === cart[j].toLowerCase()){
                cart.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```